# Math.floor() - is my understanding correct?

Tags: string, function

In this function, string.length / 2 should = 5/2, or 2.5.
If that is the case, then is the reason that
string[Math.floor(string.length / 2)] returns 'v' is that 'v' is located at index 2?

```
// inputs: a string: 'fever'
// 0 - f
// 1 - e
// 2 - v
// 3 - e
// 4 - r

// outputs: if input string is odd: return char at the midpoint of the string,
or if input string is even: return an empty string.

function findMiddleChar(string) {
// if input string is even
if(string.length % 2 === 0) {
// return an empty string
return '';
// otherwise
} else {
// return input string value at middle index(rounded down to nearest index) return string[Math.floor(string.length / 2)];
}
}
```

Comment: Which programming language do you use? Remember, the TAGS attract the right audience to your question, so if you use irrelevant tags you get the wrong audience and the audience you want don't see that question.

Comment: Pick a language, run the code and find out if you're correct! JS: `s = "fever"; console.log(s[Math.floor(s.length / 2)])`.

Comment: "if input string is odd" -> is that true if the input string is the literal `peculiar`? Please make sure that comments are accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly. In your case, 'fever'.length is 5 and and Math.floor('fever'.length / 2) will be 2, and as we count indices from 0, you will get the element located at 2nd index of the string, 'v'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the function returns 'v' because it is located at index 2.

For integer divison (type isn't double) `5/2 = 2`

You could take out the `Math.foor()` in your return statement and get the same result.

`return string[(string.length / 2)];`